# uwsgi queue of socket message flood?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I found my website unresponsive and I see a ton of

```
*** uWSGI listen queue of socket "0.0.0.0:5002" (fd: 3) full !!! (101/100) ***
*** uWSGI listen queue of socket "0.0.0.0:5002" (fd: 3) full !!! (101/100) ***
*** uWSGI listen queue of socket "0.0.0.0:5002" (fd: 3) full !!! (101/100) ***
```

Am I being ddosed? What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

The application is currently busy processing 100 requests. It is rejecting further requests.

Maybe you're being DDoS, maybe the application is very slow or blocked, maybe there are too many users and too little hardware resources for the application. Can't tell which case this is without further information.

Look into this. I don't know what WSGI tools you are using to give you the exact settings for your environment.

**Increase the number of workers/processes**. Each worker can process one request at a time. Multiple workers will be able to process multiple requests in parallel, usually 1 worker per core.

**Increase the listening queue to 500**. A moderate amount of users could generate bursts of a hundred requests at times. It takes a bigger queue to handle that amount of traffic, assuming there is enough resources to process these requests shortly.

**Check your application**. Make sure it's working and efficient. There are a hundred requests pending, is this normal? The application might be slow, hanging or lacking resources.

Answer (score 0):

remembering to raise the net.core.somaxconn to 200 with:

```
sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=200
```

or make it permanent from your /etc/sysctl.conf conf file

Answer (score -2):

Add uwsgi config:

```
processes = 8
threads = 4
max-fd = 120000
listen = 1024
```

Comment: You should include an explanation of what this does.

Comment: This is not a solution, simply a patch. The problem is likely to be in the application logic.

Comment: `threads` and `processes` are synonymous in uWSGI; so the settings here are logically inconsistent. It's not a train-smash, but it is worth understanding in order to get the expected results.